# Sending commands to AVR from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, avr

I need to send commands Xmega from node server using serialport.
For example I want my commands to be in following format:
< M 500

where:

< marks the beginning of command (string)

M is command (string)

500 is integer value (can be between 0 to 500)

Is it possible to send commands like this over serial port? If so then do I have to send my commands as buffer?

How can I insert intgers like 500 into buffer? need to convert into hex bytes (how)?

If commands are sent as buffer how does the input data look on Xmega side? All elements from the buffer are coming in 1 by 1?

Regards,
Margus

Answer (score 1):

The protocol behind the "Serial Port" is [RS-232](https://wcscnet.com/tutorials/introduction-to-rs232-serial-communication/).
As every communication protocol it deals with symbols and frames and it is agnostic of the payload it is transmitting.

This means that the payload format is totally up to you.
*RS-232* can handle 8-bit payload so you don't need any fancy bit manipulation even when sending binary data (I assume, of course, your machine has 8 bit bytes).

**So, long story short, you can send whatever you want.**

### Writing to Serial Port, server side

I have absolutely no idea why you want to use node.js to do this since JS has no concept of integers (I don't know Node.js however, it may have. In that case ignore last sentence).
Anyway in order to write to the serial port you need help from your OS.
If you are using Linux, you can start from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117037/how-to-send-data-to-a-serial-port-and-see-any-answer).
Basically writing to serial port is like writing to a file.
On Windows, you do the [same](https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/simple-trick-for-sending-characters-to-a-serial-port-in-windows/).

All of this boils down to writing a string to a file, I assume you know how to do it in Node.js.

**Don't forget** to properly set the settings (Bound rate, parity, start/stop) of the *RS-232*. Seriously, don't.

### Reading from Serial Port, AVR side

This is very easy, it just boils down to handling a bunch of register.
I'm not gonna explain how to do it in details as you can reach the AVR datasheet for more information.

Anyway [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tut-soft-using-usart-interrupt-driven-serial-comms?page=all) a page which shows how to read the serial port avoiding polling.

### Payload format

Since on the *XMega* side you will receive the payload one octet at a time, having variable length message, with integer coded as string would be just a pain the on back.
This however depends on which language you are more comfortable with.

**If I were you** I would choose a simple payload format:

```
op immediate
```

Where `op` is a 8 bit *opcode*, something like

```
00h = Nop
01h = Command 1
02h = Command 2
...
```

and `immediate` is a two octets field of data for the command.
This way every command is three octets long, you collect these three octets and then start the processing.

**One problem you should be aware of is synchronization.**

If for same reason you server and the *XMega* software go out of sync, no future command will be correctly processed.

You can use an autosync technique, like *UTF-8* do: reserve the MSb of each octet for sync.

```
0ooo oooo   10ii iiii    11ii iiii


ooo oooo = 7 bit opcode
ii iiii ii iiii = 12 bit immediate
```

Where the digit bits are fixed and the letter bits are the actual payload: *o* are the bits of the (7-bit) opcode and *i* are the bit of the (12-bit) payload).

This give you 128 possible commands, each one with a number up to 4095 as operand and you can easily tell which position in the command a byte is from, allowing you to recover from loss of synchronization.

You can further shrink this down to two octets if you need no more that 32 commands

```
0ooo ooii 1iii iiii
```

This gives 5 bit opcode and 9 bit (Up to 512) operands. Auto synchronized.